# How do I control the WooCommerce product gallery flex-control-nav and flex-control-thumbs lists?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, flexslider

I'm building a simple store using WooCommerce to sell a book in a photography website. It's working fine and looking good, except that when the window is resized the thumbnails, which are wrapped by the plugin in an `ol` with the classes `flex-control-nav` and `flex-control-thumbs` go from sitting neatly under the main image to matching it in size and reformatting themselves at the code level.

In Firefox this takes the form of a series of `div`s with the class `woocommerce-product-gallery__image`. These `div`s have inline styling which overrides CSS in the theme stylesheet.

In chrome the `ol` is replaced by `div class=""`, with the images still being called inside `li` elements.

It doesn't seem to be related to viewport width – if I refresh the page after causing the issue the original `ol` layout returns. I'm quite stumped by this – the only thing I can think of is that the jQuery required for flexslider is being affected by the viewport resizing, but I can't figure out how to get it to reload on resize.

Live example – https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/product/form-function/. Resize the browser window to replicate the issue.

Here's the page on load:

[image: Before]

Here it is after resizing (Firefox `div` issue):

[image: Text]

How can I troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: Could be a theme issue or setting disabling Slick slider sloppily upon screen re-size. Even at desktop width there is a javascript error referring to slickOptions. At lower screnwidths additional errors are introduced, and at smartphone widths in Chrome emulator no images load at all.

Comment: Could be a theme issue or setting disabling Slick slider sloppily upon screen re-size. Even at desktop width there is a javascript error referring to slickOptions. At lower screnwidths additional errors are introduced, and at smartphone widths in Chrome emulator no images load at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK you have some errors on the page that need to be addressed to fix this issue. First there is an error:

```
jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: slickOptions is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):494)
    at e (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

This one is cause `slickOptions` is not on the page for the script to use.

Next there is this error (fired on resize):

```
(index):501 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slick' of undefined
    at (index):501
    at dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

This one is from some inline jQuery:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @mikerojas. I am not going to be able to dig into this immediately but will report back when I do – i appreciate the pointers.

Comment: i have had a good look at this and found some issues with the js, as you suggested. that said, i've now got a version of the site that spits out no errors (for me at least) but i'm still seeing the issue. [link](https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/product/form-function/)